# Using "the" for a class and for a member of a class

Tags: definite-article

> I will have you, the Glumor, wiped out completely!

If we know that the word "Glumor" is in singular and we are not aware of any further context, then will it be correct to say that we don't know whether "the Glumor" refers to a group (like a nation, or a race) or to a member of a group?

And conversely, if there were no definite article in that sentence:

> I will have you, Glumor, wiped out completely!

would it be correct then to say that since "Glumor" is in singular and there is no "the", then it is definitely a reference to only one member of a group?

Comment: If there's no article I would assume it to  be a personal name.

Comment: "wiped out" as a threat only makes sense when referring to a group. You could use it to refer to an individuals' assets, or their standing in a game or military context, but again the wiped out would refer to a group of things. Their money, their pieces, their soldiers.

Comment: Using *the* doesn't make something singular.  For example, it could be "You, the Russians..."

Comment: @stangdon - In my example, "Glumor" is a singular form.

Comment: Idiomatically, when applied to a plural referent, ***to be wiped out*** means ***to be completely eliminated***. But when applied to a *singular* referent, it means ***to lose all one's money / assets***. Presumably OP knows whether "the Glumor" is singular or plural, which is all that's relevant here. If it's "a reference to only one member of a group", that could be expressed by *I will have you, **a Glumor**, wiped out completely!* ( = I will strip you *[who are a Glumor]* of all your wealth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bordering on the absurd to ask a question about how to use a word properly in English when the word does not even exist in English.

Is “Glumor” a noun, verb, or adjective. If we presume, from the initial capital letter and the surrounding syntactical structure, that “Glumor” is a proper noun (a presumption not justified by anything the OP has bothered to state explicitly), then we cannot be sure whether “Glumor” has a singular or collective referent.

> I defy the man to demonstrate this.

> I defy the committee to demonstrate this

are both grammatical. One refers to a single individual. The other refers to multiple individuals considered as a single collective.

Moreover, if we conclude that “Glumor” represents multiple individuals

> you, the Glumor,

may refer to the collective as a single entity, or it may refer to a unique individual from that collective in some designated group. This is usually disambiguated by a plural marking:

> You, the graduates,

> You, the graduate,

But we do not know whether “Gumor” is singular or plural or ambivalent as to number like “fish.”

> You, the fish, have gills.

Are we talking about one specific fish or fish in general? Syntax will not answer that question.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear explanations!